# Asymptotic complexity in its simplest form

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm studying for my computer science exams and I've came across a few questions on simplifying asymptotic complexity and i'm unsure how far too take it. For example:

- Give '2n log(n) + 3 log(n)' in its simplest form.

Which i would consider to be n log n. 
Is this correct and is there a method for determining exactly how specific i should be?

Other questions given were:

- 4 log₄(n + 1)
- 2n log(n) + 1/2⋅n²
- 4n² + 3<sup>n</sup>

And my respective guesses:

- log n
- n²
- 3<sup>n</sup>

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Don't worry about the down-voting too much.  Check out the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask better questions.  It's common to help new people with some tips when you downvote, but not everyone is that nice.

Comment: Technically, your edit about downvoting is not part of your question and would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: In Big-O notation, you only have to take the fastest growing part of the sum (if the sum has a constant number of summands) and you can strip off every constant factors.

So your guesses are correct.

In general you should study the [mathematical definition of Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) for more details.
If you are familiar with the math, you can simplify it with all mathematical methods you know.